# CSS clip-path breaks pseudo ::before element stack order

Tags: css, pseudo-element, clip-path

I'm trying to create a frosted glass effect on a non-rectangular element but it's not working out. I'm experiencing an odd issue that I can't seem to wrap my head around...

The frosted glass effect is easy to accomplish by setting a fixed background-image on the document body, adding a partially transparent background color to the element and creating a ::before pseudo element with the same fixed background-image and applying a blur filter. Like so:

```
  body {
    background: url(bg-lanterns.jpg) 0 / cover fixed;
  }

  main {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    padding: 1rem;
    height: 600px;
    width: 800px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  }

  main::before {
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: url(bg-lanterns.jpg) 0 / cover fixed;
    filter: blur(10px);
  }
```

[image: frosted glass effect]

Creating a non-rectangular element is also easy by using [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) like this:

```
  main {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    padding: 1rem;
    height: 600px;
    width: 800px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
```

[image: non-rectangular element]

But trying to combine these two effects breaks the stacking order and causes the ::before element to appear above the white background.

[image: broken]

I get the same result in Chrome and Firefox so I'm wondering if this is the expected behavior and I'm simply doing something wrong... Can anybody shed some light on what is happening here?

Here's a live demo:

```css
      body {
        background: url(https://i.imgur.com/y1TH8fR.jpg) 0 / cover fixed;
      }
      
      main {
        position: relative;
        margin: 1rem auto;
        padding: 1rem;
        height: 600px;
        width: 800px;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
        clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
      }
      
      main::before {
        content: '';
        z-index: -1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        padding: 1rem;
        background: url(https://i.imgur.com/y1TH8fR.jpg) 0 / cover fixed;
        filter: blur(10px);
      }
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Comment: Could you share a live example?

Comment: I added a snippet.

Comment: So do you need to get rid of these white top/bottom shadows, right? Or instead, do you need to get the white blur effect?

Comment: The final result should have the blurry white effect to the background like in the first screenshot but with the angled dimensions of the second second screenshot (notice that the background is only transparent white and not blurred in the second image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the specification for `clip-path`:

> A computed value of other than none results in the creation of a stacking context [CSS21] the same way that CSS opacity [CSS3COLOR] does for values other than 1.

I managed to achieve the desired effect by adding the white color to an ::after pseudo element and clipping both pseudo elements instead of the element itself.

```css
      body {
        background: url(https://i.imgur.com/y1TH8fR.jpg) 0 / cover fixed;
      }
      
      main {
        position: relative;
        margin: 1rem auto;
        height: 600px;
        width: 800px;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        align-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      main::before,
      main::after {
        content: '';
        z-index: -1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
      }
      
      main::before {
        background: url(https://i.imgur.com/y1TH8fR.jpg) 0 / cover fixed;
        filter: blur(10px);
      }
      
      main::after {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
      }
```

```html
<main> <span> test </span> </main>
```

Comment: That's exact solution what I was about to add. Yes, there is a definitely some index change after adding clip-path to initial element.

Comment: So it would seem. I find that to be rather strange behavior but apparently it's per the spec (https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking-1/#the-clip-path). I actually had to add z-index: -1 to ::before and ::after otherwise my content ended up buried at the bottom of the stack.